# Add objects to FabricJS topContext

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas, fabricjs

Trying to draw objects on `fabric.js` **ctx** ( to prevent selection / z-index, and make something like rulers at the top of canvas) but after `mouse:wheel` i see strange stack effect with my drawn object. But on 'selection' event, **ctx** clears and works fine. Can't understand why `mouse:wheel` and `after:render` and other events in **fabric.js** works so strange and how i can fix this. Thanks!

[here's fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/917xp26g/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found solution, just add `clearContext` method inside `before:render` in my case

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6nt28voz/)